# Pandas - Importing CSV issue - adding and deleting 0 at the end

Tags: python, pandas, csv, floating-point, series

I want to import a csv dataset. 
My problem is when I import the base, pandas kinds of try to convert it into something.

Let me explain with numbers.
This is more or less how my csv file is.

```
> Data, Id, Text

>2018-06-11, 17980873.3391, bla bla bla 

>2018-06-11, 17980874.4560, bla bla bla

>2018-06-11, 17980876.8560, bla bla bla
```

The trouble is when I import it with pd.read_csv. The Id column should be exactly the way it is in csv file (I want to use it as a filter to do searches) . But pandas is returning something like:

When I import with no changes in the structure (pandas transform the column into float automatically)

```
> Data, Id, Text

>2018-06-11, 17980873.33910, bla bla bla 

>2018-06-11, 17980874.45600, bla bla bla

>2018-06-11, 17980876.85600, bla bla bla
```

when I import the dataset and transform the id column as type(str):

```
> Data, Id, Text

>2018-06-11, 17980873.3391, bla bla bla 

>2018-06-11, 17980874.456, bla bla bla

>2018-06-11, 17980876.856, bla bla bla
```

It is deleting and adding 0. 
I really don't know how to make pandas import the real number

```
>17980876.8560
```

Hope I've made myself understood. I'm still learning how to ask questions here.

Thanks!

Comment: When you import the data using `.read_csv()`, set the dtype of the "Id" column to `object` using the `dtype` option with a dict. See documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @smj, Sorry, this is a bad idea. There are better ways to compare floats than to read as strings. Given OP refers to `17980873.3391` as a number rather than a category, I can only believe it should be treated a number.

Comment: Thanks, man! I fixed my issue for good with dtype. I should pay more attention to the docs... my bad. Thanks again!

Comment: @jpp You are assuming the data is a float.  The OP implies it is an ID with an 8.4 ID, which is probably just a string.  The OP can clarify.

Comment: The compare I would like to do is the exactly ID number. It is possible to find the id 17980876.8560 looking for 17980876.856000 with the np.isclose parameter?  Would this be faster than use as string ou object?

Comment: @CristianFavaroCarriço, Yes, it will match it. And yes, it will be faster.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, out of interest, is there a difference/benefit from setting it to `str` instead of `object` ?

Comment: @smj not that I know of, but I'm not a heavy user of pandas.

Comment: Another note about `str` vs. float.  If an "ID" fields has "111.500" and "111.50" and "111.5" those will all compare the same as floats, but different as strings.  So for the OP using float will be faster, but incorrect if the zeros in your IDs are significant.  Just something to be aware of.

Comment: @jpp I take your point that if it is a float, treating it as such and use `isclose()` would be best. Hadn't seen that before so thanks for the info! If it is in fact an ID, maybe it would actually be better to split the columns on the `.` and store them as `int`. Could be quite useful for grouping...

Comment: @MarkTolonen, Excellent point. But OP has already asked `It is possible to find the id 17980876.8560 looking for 17980876.856000.. ?` So it seems to be fine. If *either* method works for OP's purposes, IMO we should propagate the `float` comparison first (there's no memory/performance trade-off here, it's `float` all the way).

Comment: @jpp Agreed, we don't always get the full story from new users so I wanted to point out possible problems.

Comment: Thanks, folks. It helped me a lot. I liked the suggestions from @smj to split the columns on the . and store them as int. I think this is gonna be great for my search propose. About the possible problemns, I totally agree with you, Mark Tolonen. The search will be made by a robot that I've been developing, so there might be some ID with conflit. This ID is from a page I´m trying to scrap. Always when some new report apears on this page, the scrap program check if this report's ID its been added to the list. If wasn't, the robot will send me an e-mail notifying me of new posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `dtype` for the `Id` to `str` for no translation.

Given:

```
Data,Id,Text
2018-06-11,17980873.3391,bla bla bla
2018-06-11,17980874.4560,bla bla bla
2018-06-11,17980876.8560,bla bla bla
```

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv',dtype={'Id':str})
print(data)
```

To get:

```
         Data             Id         Text
0  2018-06-11  17980873.3391  bla bla bla
1  2018-06-11  17980874.4560  bla bla bla
2  2018-06-11  17980876.8560  bla bla bla
```

This does assume your ID field is intended to be an 8-digit dot 4-digit string and not a floating point value.

Answer (score 1):

You should first understand that Pandas isn't reading in your number as a decimal `17980873.33910`. It is reading it into your dataframe as a `float`, which counts in base-2 rather than base-10. Any numbers you see thenceforth is a **string representation** of a `float`, nothing more.

In general, you shouldn't be looking to convert numeric data to strings. The process is expensive, any comparisons are expensive and you will be dealing with a series of pointers rather than data held in **contiguous memory blocks**. The last point is a principle benefit of using Pandas, as it enables **vectorised operations**.

Now to your core problem:

> The Id column should be exactly the way it is in csv file (I want to
>   use it as a filter to do searches).

You should use [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) to compare floats. This function works by setting a tolerance level, within which two numbers are deemed to be the same. Here's an example:

```
s = pd.Series([1.4532400, 67.1234, 54.4556, 765.32414])
res = np.isclose(s, 1.45324)

print(res)
array([ True, False, False, False])
```

Then to filter your series:

```
s_filtered = s[res]

print(s_filtered)

0    1.45324
dtype: float64
```

Here's a performance comparison:

```
s = pd.Series([1.4532400, 67.1234, 54.4556, 765.32414])
s = pd.concat([s]*100000)
s2 = s.astype(str)

%timeit np.isclose(s, 1.45324)       # 5.02 ms
%timeit s2.astype(str) == '1.45324'  # 79.5 ms
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely follow your tips in my code. At a first look, I fixed it with the dtype parameter. But I`m gonna try to implement the isclose parameter right now.