# pandas adding .0 when I import from CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My problem is when I import the base, pandas kinds of try to convert it into a number?

This is more or less how my csv file is.

```
Data,ID,Text

2018-06-11,20995, bla bla bla 

2018-06-11,17980, bla bla bla

2018-06-11,46854, bla bla bla
```

The trouble is when I import it with pd.read_csv. The Id column should be exactly the way it is in csv files. But pandas is returning something like:

```
Data,ID,Text

2018-06-11,20995.0, bla bla bla 

2018-06-11,17980.0, bla bla bla

2018-06-11,46854.0, bla bla bla
```

I've tried using the dtype during the readin

```
df= pd.read_csv('df.csv',encoding ='latin1',dtype={'ID':str})
```

but it still adds the .0. When I look at the csv it does not have these tailing .0

I've also tried to converting to string after

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str)
```

I want to be clear that I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958377/pandas-importing-csv-issue-adding-and-deleting-0-at-the-end) and the responses didn't answer my Q

Comment: Missing values in column `ID` force pandas to convert to `float`. The column's name is `' ID'`, your are missing a whitespace. Are the `>` at the start of every line part of your CSV file?

Comment: yes there are missing values in ID which is ok in my case. the column name is 'ID' I was just putting spaces for clarity. same thing with '>'. I have removed those as apparently they lead to less clarity.

Comment: With your new example data I cannot reproduce your result (using `pandas 1.1.5`). Your code reads column `ID` as `string` without changing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hit the worst pandas wart of all times. But it's 2022, and missing values for integers are finally supported! Check this out. Here is a csv file, with integer column `a` that has a missing value:

```
a,b
1,y
2,m
,c
3,a
```

If you read it in a default manner you get the annoying conversion to float:

`pd.read_csv('test.csv'):`

```
    a       b
--------------
0   1.0     y
1   2.0     m
2   NaN     c
3   3.0     a
```

But, if you tell pandas that you want new experimental integers with missing values, you get the good stuff:
`pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype={'a': 'Int64'}):`

```
    a   b
---------
0   1   y
1   2   m
2 <NA>  c
3   3   a
```

Comment: While your answer is the correct solution it doesn't explain why `dtype={'ID': str}` isn't working. A [nullable integer type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html) is supported in stable since january 2020.

Comment: I tried that and got 'ValueError: Unable to parse string "NEW"'

Comment: also I assume the colon at the end was a typo?

Comment: holy shit the word 'new' was in my IDs. I'm a moron

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny You are right, `dtype={'ID': str}` should work as well, and it works for me on the test example. @elcunyado, If you have non-integer values, try `dtype={'ID': str}` one more time, it really should work.